# AWS users can no longer change their own passwords, keys and mfa's

Tags: permissions, amazon-web-services

I created some permissions so my users can change their own passwords, access keys, and mfa devices, using these references:
[Allows users to change their own passwords](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_passwords_enable-user-change.html)
[Enable self-managed passwords only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_my-sec-creds-self-manage-password-only.html)
[Enable self-managed access keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_my-sec-creds-self-manage-pass-accesskeys-ssh.html)
[Enable self-managed mfa/creds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_users-self-manage-mfa-and-creds.html)

Two days ago this stopped working.  Now, users receive a message that says they don't have permission to change their credentials. Has anything changed regarding these permissions in the past few days?

Comment: Suggest you ask the question on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), including the policies and error messages. Nothing has changed in AWS that would cause this, most likely explanation is incorrect policy or the policy hasn't been applied to the appropriate group / user.